# react native drawer navigation on Press Item action

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, asyncstorage, react-navigation-drawer

In my drawer navigator, there is log out button when I press on logout. I want to remove `app_token` but I don't know how.

I try to put something like this:

```
onItemPress:() => { AsyncStorage.removeItem('app_token')},
```

But it did not work.

```
const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({



      Logout: {

    onItemPress:() => { AsyncStorage.removeItem('app_token')},

          screen: HomePage,
          navigationOptions: {


              drawerIcon: (
                  <Image style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
                         source={require('./assets/IconDrawerNavigation/logout.png')} />
              )
          }
      },
```

}
  );

Comment: are you solve it?

Comment: yes i solve it i will add comment below

Answer (score 1):

to solve this problem i use props called contentComponent from this props you can create your own drawer

```
import drawerContentComponents from './Drawer';

const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({

  Home: {screen: Home,}
  },

},
  {contentComponent: drawerContentComponents,}

  );
```

//Drawer source code

```
//i use this library so i can restart the app and logout 
import RNRestart from 'react-native-restart'; 

export default class drawerContentComponents extends Component {


    _logout = () => {
        AsyncStorage.removeItem('sale_id');
        RNRestart.Restart();

    }
    render() {


        return (

            <View style={styles.container2}>

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('profile')} >
                    <View style={styles.screenStyle}>
                        <Image style={styles.iconStyle}
                            source={home} />
                        <Text style={styles.screenTextStyle}>My Profile</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.underlineStyle} />
                </TouchableOpacity>


                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('social')} >
                    <View style={styles.screenStyle}>
                        <Image style={styles.iconStyle}
                            source={home} />
                        <Text style={styles.screenTextStyle}>Contact US</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.underlineStyle} />
                </TouchableOpacity>



                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._logout} >
                    <View style={styles.screenStyle}>
                        <Image style={styles.iconStyle}
                            source={home} />
                        <Text style={styles.screenTextStyle}>Logout</Text>
                    </View>

                </TouchableOpacity>


            </View>

        )
    }
}
```